What are the advantages of an eight diode 3 phase full bridge rectifier?
I'm replacing my car's alternator, and tearing the old one apart, as you do. The alternator is wired in a Y configuration with 8 diodes, 2 on the neutral point, and then the standard 2 on each of the phases.
I haven't seen that design before, and I'm curious what the reasons might be for choosing it. I'm not terribly good with AC or magnetics, so I'm trying to wrap my head around the results of adding in the neutral point to the rectifier- and the only thing I'm really coming to is it might be useful in the event of a diode failing open- it provides an alternate path for current to enter/exit the windings.
My bad attempt at putting it in a simulator: circuit sim ; in that trivial case no current is flowing through neutral; and when simulating an open diode, with neutral connected and disconnected, a similar fall in output is seen at the load.
Example from https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-diagram-of-the-eight-diode-rectifier-circuit_fig3_343719078 ; paper is unrelated to a 1993 alternator. Probably. Though they do claim "the voltage of the neutral point belongs to the third harmonic", but that's over my head.


Not just the diodes.. But if one of the windings fails, they also help. Also, if the phases aren't installed at 120° apart, or when the alternator speed changes quickly, you could get some imbalance of the three phases

And we know that a car's motor changes speed a lot and sometimes quickly.

This page claims it is related to regulator operation, but I can't figure out how.

@jpa I think he might be talking about the regulator taking the neutral point as an input / reference point. Not sure why though. As it happens, my alternator does have the 'stator core sampling circuit' (online I've heard that called a diode-trio, so my alternator is actually 11 diodes total; but the neutral point isn't fed to the regulator), and my understanding from reading online is that the stator excitation is done with current from the diode trio. Except during ignition/starting, when it may be fed through an indicator lamp...

I revisited the circuit simulation: the original simulation was a set of 3 voltage ac sources 120 degrees out of phase; I changed this to a set of poorly hacked together current ac sources, which should be a better match for the coils in an alternator, I think. See new simulation here.
In the original simulation, the neutral diodes did have an effect in the event of diodes failing open or coils disconnecting, but it was a very minor effect- you'd see 75% of power instead of 66% and a high ripple. In the new simulation, the diodes have a significant effect- if a coil drops out you end up seeing the same power at the load, with no noticeable change in output (which is not at all what I expected).
So I'd be willing to say a large part of the decision would be the 8 diode approach does handle potential failures much better. (and I can't prove it, but I'd think there are mechanical benefits as well during coil failures- more consistent load so less vibration)
There may be other reasons that I can't really model in the simulation- I'm assuming the field strength is constant, rpm is constant, etc.

After slowing down the "Current Speed" slider, I really enjoyed staring at that simulation for a solid 3 minutes, just watching the 3-phase currents balance out. Particularly at the N combining point. Thanks!

Outside the automotive context, rectifiers on N-side are beneficial to have the load supplied even on single phase i.e. when two phases are lost.
In 3-ph balanced operation the N current is zero. So without the rectifiers on N-side, the load still sees 3-ph rectified voltage, which has a peak of \$\sqrt3\$ times the line (phase-to-phase) voltage, or approximately \$\sqrt6\$ times the RMS of a phase. The ripple will be quite low, and the average (DC) voltage will be high i.e. \$3\sqrt3/\pi\approx1.6\$ times the peak (or ~1.16 times of the RMS) of a phase (assuming each phase has equal phase-to-neutral voltage).
If one phase is lost i.e. 2-ph operation, the load can still be supplied even if there is no rectifiers on the N-side. The peak will be approximately the same, but the avg (DC) voltage across the load will be lower and with excessive ripple.
If two phases are lost, the load cannot be supplied if there's no rectifiers on N-side. But with rectifiers on N-side, the system turns into a single-phase full bridge rectifier. However, the peak will be less (i.e. peak of the remaining phase), the ripple ratio will be quite high, and the average (DC) voltage will be \$2/\pi=0.636\$ times the peak of the remaining phase.
NOTE: No filtering/smoothing capacitors are shown in your schematic so I assumed there was none. If there was a capacitor, the ripple current flowing through it increases as the effective number of phases decreases therefore it's maximum in single-phase operation.
